# How to remove Pycharm's point of view regarding my code? If I have a mistake - so it will not show it is wrong

Tags: python

Sorry for bad title, I dont know how to say it in my language ( so especially in english ).
Lets say I am working for a code, I make a grammer mistake, forget "" or other stuff, how to remove all the help from pycharm?
I am studying for a final test in my university for Python and I wont want pycharm helping me, I want to realize my mistakes myself, not pycharm helping me.
Please help, atleast tell me what to write at google so I know how to remove it.

EDIT: can anyone help? Inspection and such will not work. I am still in this problem.

Comment: Don't use pycharm. There are lots of good text editors and simple IDEs out there. Pretty much the whole point of pycharm is to offer that extra help.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yea but still, Is there any way with pycharm? or there isnt at all? and what kind of text editors has that? but still, if pycharm is able to do it, I will be happy to know how.
What should I write? since I dont know what to write in google for it

Comment: You should disable proofreading/typo from settings

Comment: @crissal Hi thanks, I did it, removed all inspections, but I still has it

Comment: @BenShaines. Depends on what you want to keep. It's a pretty broad spectrum from notepad to pycharm. I would suggest something like gedit, which stops at syntax highlighting

Comment: @MadPhysicist hmm I want to remove all help from pycharm, I did un-V from all Inspections, as it wrote at google

Comment: You can also try unchecking Settings/Editor/Inspections/Proofreading

Comment: @crissal it wont work, I already removed all at inspections, all stuff there and still I see all